# What framework need for create real time sound effects in iOS

Tags: ios, frameworks, soundeffect

I create new app. For my new app I want to create sound effects for my music which play in real time. someone know what framework need for it?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [AVFoundation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundationFramework/_index.html) framework.  You can use the [AVAudioPlayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008067) class like this:

```
NSString * fPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"audiofile.mp3"];
NSURL * url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:fPath];
AVAudioPlayer * audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url
                                                                     error:nil];
audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;
[audioPlayer play];
```